# VR Controller Tooltip in Unity

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I'm looking to implement tooltips on VR controllers (e.g. controller highlights, text overlays) in Unity (e.g., Oculus Quest, XR interaction toolkit). I have seen an old solution based on VRTK.

How can I do this?

Comment: We don't answer questions asking for suggestions of libraries / frameworks here. What we can do is offer solutions to specific problems. So, what problem do you encounter when you try to implement a tooltip in VR in Unity based on what you know and have found so far?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your clarification. In principle, I know how to implement the tooltip. However, I like to avoid as much as possible to recode an easily accessible feature. I also don't have a strict feature list, but I would rather work around on any given limitations. I can nonetheless, be more clear in the parts which seem like double work.